# Finding the dimension of these ${\mathbb{R}}^4$ subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector subspaces $W_1 = \{(x, y, z, t) \in\mathbb R^4 \mid −y + t = 0,\ z + x = 0\}$ and $W_2 = \{(x, y, z, t) \in\mathbb R^4 \mid −2x + 2y − 2t + 2z = 0\}$ from $\mathbb R^4$.
Find their dimensions: $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} (W_1), \dim_{\mathbb{R}} (W_2)$.

I found that $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}W_1 = 2$

(Row Reduction)

$$[1,0,1, 0]$$
$$[0,1,0, -1]$$

But how do I find the dimension of $W_2$?

Comment: In these questions I always like to think "how many independent parameters are there?" and that's the dimension. In $W_2$ I think the answer is 3.

Answer (score 1):

We have $-2x+2y-2t+2z=0\implies x-y-z+t=0$. Now see one variable $t$ (say) depends upon others.

It's easy to see the set $\{(1,0,0,-1),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,1)\}$ is a set of LI vectors.

You can prove that this is the basis as any vector in $W_2$ is of the form $(x,y,z,t)=(x,y,z,y+z-x)=x(1,0,0,-1)+y(0,1,0,1)+z(0,0,1,1)$.